# Defining functions with a rule

Tags: function-construction

A have a list of coefficients, and each one of them depends on xp, which I haven't defined so far. For example, A[[1]] reads:

```
A[[1]]=-((I (a^2 m^2 + 2 (-1 + xp)^2 λ + 
a m (I - I xp + 2 (-2 + Q^2) ω) + ω (Q^4 ω + 
   2 xp (-I + 2 ω - xp^3 ω + xp (I + ω)) + 
   Q^2 (I - 2 ω + 2 xp^2 ω - 
      xp (I + 4 ω)))))/(4 (-1 + xp)^2 (I + a m + Q^2 ω - xp (I + 2 ω))))
```

Later on, I define xp as a function of a and Q. So I would like to do something like this:

```
y[a_, Q_] := A[[1]] /. xp -> xp[a, Q]
```

However, when I compute y[0,0], this is what I get:

```
-((I (a^2 m^2 + a m (I + 2 (-2 + Q^2) ω - I xp[0, 0]) + 
   2 λ (-1 + xp[0, 0])^2 + ω (Q^4 ω + 
      Q^2 (I - 2 ω - (I + 4 ω) xp[0, 0] + 
         2 ω xp[0, 0]^2) + 
      2 xp[0, 0] (-I + 
         2 ω + (I + ω) xp[0, 0] - ω xp[0, 
           0]^3))))/(4 (-1 + xp[0, 0])^2 (I + a m + 
   Q^2 ω - (I + 2 ω) xp[0, 0])))
```

The a's and Q's are not 0, except when they are arguments of the function xp[a,Q].

My question is: how can I define y[a_,Q_] such that the a's and Q's get replaced by whatever values are given to the function?

Comment: Try using `Set`(=) instead of `SetDelayed`. `y[a_, Q_] = A[[1]] /. xp -> xp[a, Q]`.

Comment: Now the output is simply y[0,0]

Comment: I can't figure what you are asking. Mathematica did exactly what you asked it to do. It replaced `xp` with `xp[0,0]` as you told it. So what is the issue? When later you call `y[1,1]` say, it will now replace `xp` with `xp[1,1]` and so on.

Comment: I want to define the function y[a,Q] in such a way that the a's and Q's appearing in the expression are replaced by, say, 1 and 2 respectively, when I call the function y[1,2].

Comment: Then just do as Anjan suggested. Write `y[a_, q_] = A0 /. xp -> xp[a, q]` ? This will replace `xp` by `xp[a,q]` first, and the result, is the body of the function. It is important to know the difference between `=` and `:=` in function definition. (But I still do not see what difference this will make in your case, as the final result will be the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work as you intend?

```
y[a2_, Q2_] := A[[1]] /. {xp -> xp[a2, Q2],a->a2,Q->Q2}
```